# When I run npm run preview, only one page is found, but when I run npm run dev all my pages are found

Tags: file, terminal, svelte, sveltekit

so this is my first time using sveltekit and a framework in general. It was really easy to use, but when I deployed it, I ran into a problem. When I was building my webpage with npm run dev, everything was working perfectly, but when I deployed it or ran npm run preview, every time I clicked on the links, it would give a 404 not found error. The goal was to create one title page with 9 links, and every time a link is clicked, it'll send you to a different webpage.

```
<div class="title">
    <h1 class=bigTitle>Best Jpop Groups in the Business</h1>
    <p>and you can't tell me otherwise</p>
</div>
<ol class="ranking-row">
    <div>
        <a href="src/routes/Uru-Page">
            <li id="Uru">Uru</li>
            <img alt="The singer Uru" src={Uru}/>
        </a>
    </div>
```

I tried installing a vercel adapter in the hopes that when the webpage was deployed the problem would be fixed, but then no page was found at all. I tried playing with the file pathways I set for the href in my anchor tag, but that also didn't work. I also tried this line of code (at the bottom) which chatgpt suggested putting into the svelte.config.js file, but it didn't work either. By the way, I just put all my webpages in the routes folder. Could that be the problem?

```
export default {
  kit: {
    // ...
    paths: {
      base: '/myapp', // Example base path
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That `href` is wrong, the dev server might serve it, but the build will definitely not as there will be no `src`.

It should be:

```html
<script>
  import { base } from '$app/paths';
</script>
<a href="{base}/Uru-Page">
```

I.e. `src/routes` should *not* appear and the `base` has to be used (*if* you have it configured, that is).

Answer (score 0):

```
- <a href="src/routes/Uru-Page">
+ <a href="/Uru-Page">
```

Try removing the `src/routes` prefix. Example from the [docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page).

```html
<!-- src/routes/+page.svelte -->
<h1>Hello and welcome to my site!</h1>
<a href="/about">About my site</a>

<!-- src/routes/about/+page.svelte -->
<h1>About this site</h1>
<p>TODO...</p>
<a href="/">Home</a>
```